# AngularJS : Call controller function from a directive with isolated scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have the following problem. I would like to call controller function from a directive with isolated scope.

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="MainController">
   <test></test>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("MainController", function ($scope) {
    $scope.testFunction = function () {
        console.log("You just call testFunction()!");
    };
});

app.directive("test", function () {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        scope: {},
        template: "<h1 ng-click='testFunction()'>Hello world!</h1>"
    };
});
```

When directive don't have an isolated scope, the call function follows.

[Working DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/niezbor/9xtm77x2/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass the function to be called using `&` like

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("MainController", function($scope) {
  $scope.counter = 0;
  $scope.testFunction = function() {
    $scope.counter++;
  };
});

app.directive("test", function() {
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    scope: {
      myfn: '&myfn'
    },
    template: "<h1 ng-click='myfn()'>Hello world!</h1>"
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainController">
  <test myfn="testFunction()"></test>
  <span>{{counter}}</span>
</div>
```